# Is there a simpler way to fetch the id from xml using xpath

Tags: xml, selenium, xpath

```
<table class="xju" id="pt1:_d_reg:region2:1:dtrt_dc_4333407150" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" summary="" currentxpathtry="15">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="x15" currentmouseover="254">
                        <label class="af_panelLabelAndMessage_label-text" currentmouseover="471">Location Name</label>
                    </td>
                    <td valign="top" class="xwv xjv" currentmouseover="382">AP51</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

In the above XML, i need to fetch the **id** attribute value of **table** tag. There are n number of table tags available and only unique value text value of **label** tag. 
P.S: **table** tag is not the root tag

```
driver.getWebDriver().findElement(By.xpath("//table[tbody/tr/td/label = 'Location Name']")).getAttribute("id");
```

Instead of using **tbody/tr/td/label = 'Location Name'**, is there is way to relatively filter based on conditon value 'Location Code'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you just want to prevent entering the full path of your `lookup` element. you can use `descendant`.

```
//table[descendant::label='Location Name']/@id
```